# Regex to remove letters, symbols except numbers

Tags: javascript, regex, symbols

How can you remove letters, symbols such as `∞§¶•ªºº«≥≤÷` but leaving plain numbers 0-9, I want to be able to not allow letters or certain symbols in an input field but to leave numbers only.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4vuHN/).

If you put any symbols like `¡ € # ¢ ∞ § ¶ • ª` or else, it still does not remove it from the input field. How do you remove symbols too? The `\w` modifier does not work either.

Comment: `\w` is not a modifier but a shortcut of `[A-Za-z0-9_]` or *word characters*.

Answer (score 144, accepted):

You can use `\D` which means *non digits*.

```
var removedText = self.val().replace(/\D+/g, '');
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/ZxtXb/).

You could also use the [HTML5 *number* input](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.number.html).

```
<input type="number" name="digit" />
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/v9g5e/).

Comment: Probably want to replace more than just the first non-digit found -- change regexp to `/\D+/`

Comment: shouldn't it be `/\D+/g` ?

Comment: `/\D+/g` has the same effect as to `/\D/g`.

Comment: I find the fiddle for number input unuseful: a) it includes the javascript for removing non-numbers and b) if the above js is removed, it does nothing (for me) for the purpose of removing non-numbers

Comment: @Pere You still need to validate it yourself. It does give you the arrows for incrementing/decrementing the number though.

Comment: .keydown() is not enough if user is allowed to paste text into field.

Answer (score 43):

Use `/[^0-9.,]+/` if you want floats.

Comment: If you want a string that could contain a float value ;)

Comment: what is that "," for?

Comment: @sbk in some regions they use the comma instead of the dot to mark decimal places :)

Comment: also negatives /[^-0-9.,]+/

Comment: @KlemenTusar I tried this one with "245k" and didn't work..

Answer (score 22):

Simple:

```
var removedText = self.val().replace(/[^0-9]+/, '');
```

^ - means NOT

Comment: var removedText = self.val().replace(/[^0-9]+/g, ''); to keep all numbers. albeit 8.10+3 would give 8103... Not sure that is what's asked for in the question.

Answer (score 8):

Try the following regex:

```
var removedText = self.val().replace(/[^0-9]/, '');
```

This will match every character that is **not** (`^`) in the interval 0-9.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4vuHN/2/).

Comment: I hate being 32 seconds late :D

Answer (score 4):

If you want to keep only numbers then use `/[^0-9]+/` instead of `/[^a-zA-Z]+/`

Answer (score 0):

Excluding special characters:

`/^[^@~`!@#$%^&()_=+\';:"/?>.<,-]$/`

This regular expression helps to exclude special characters from the input.

Exclude special characters and emojis:

`/^([^\u2700-\u27BF\uE000-\uF8FF\uDD10-\uDDFF\u2011-\u26FF\uDC00-\uDFFF\uDC00-\uDFFF\u005D\u007C@~`!@#$%^&()_=+[{}"\';:"/?>.<,-\s])$/`

This is a regular expression to exclude both special characters and emojis from the input. Given are the Unicode ranges of the emojis, mathematical symbols, and symbols in other languages.