# how to remove everything except numeric 1234567890 using javascript

Tags: javascript

i have the following javascript how and where to set so when it will get the data and shows in a textbox it will show only numeric values:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function showData($sel){
   var str='';
   document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML;
   for (var i=0;i<sel.options.length;i++){
           str+=(str!='') ? ', '+sel.options[i].value : sel.options[i].value;
       }
   }
   sel.form.selectedFruits.value = str;
}
</script>
```

i have multiple select dropdown and it has multiple values like Staff No and email so i dont want to show email in text box only staff no and even i dont want to remove email from values.

it is working fine except what i want to do :D

Comment: looks like `sel` would be undefined, `$sel` is your parameter

Comment: can we see the html for the select please

Comment: Discover `.replace()`:http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp - so `.replace(/[^0-9]/, '')` will fit

Comment: this can help:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6649327/regex-to-remove-letters-symbols-except-numbers

Comment: @AlmaDoMundo Better yet, don't refer to W3Schools https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Comment: @Pavlo oops. Can not edit my comment now :\ Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution, if you want to get only numbers from a string (or html in your example), will be :

```
var str= document.getElementById(id).innerHTML;
return str.replace(/[^0-9]/ig, '');
```

See this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Qn2QV/).

Answer (score 0):

if I've gotten the point correctly try something like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function showData($sel){
   var str=[];
   document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML;
   for (var i=0;i<sel.options.length;i++){
           str[i]+=sel.options[i].value.replace(/\D/g, ''); // remove everything except digits
       }
   }
   sel.form.selectedFruits.value = str.join();
}
</script>
```

Comment: thanks your given code is not working not showing anything but i got an idea from your code and its working now only i have changed only one line in my code and i got it working:

str+=(str!='') ? ', '+sel.options[i].value.replace(/\D/g, '') : sel.options[i].value.replace(/\D/g, '');

Comment: yes I've missed the += should be  str[i]=sel.options[i].value.replace(/\D/g, ''); and I'd prefer to put values by document.getElementById("selectedFruits").value = str.join();

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function showStaffno(sel){
   var str='';
   document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML;
   for (var i=0;i<sel.options.length;i++){
       if (sel.options[i].selected){
           str+=(str!='') ? ', '+sel.options[i].value.replace(/\D/g, '') : sel.options[i].value.replace(/\D/g, '');
       }
   }
   sel.form.selectedFruits.value = str;
}
</script>
```

Comment: this is the working code / answer of this question with the help/ idea from the code of Mr. i100 ...