# JS-regex, How can I make it to one replace() method?

Tags: javascript, regex

My goal is :

Delete all.
except the numbers , but delete the zeros who before numbers 1 to 9

And I have this regex:

`var validValue = inputValue.replace(/[^\d]/g, '').replace(/^0*/g, '');`

But I want to make it in a one `replace()`

So how can I do that ?

Comment: I'm not sure you can. What's the issue of doing this in two steps?

Comment: No problem, but I want it to be shorter, if its possible
I do not know if it's possible

Comment: Where does this `inputValue` come from ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regex to remove letters, symbols except numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6649327/regex-to-remove-letters-symbols-except-numbers)

Comment: You could just use `<input type="number" name="digit" />`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to remove all leading zeros and all non-digit symbols. It can be done with

```
/^0+|\D+/g
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fS1yC8/3)

The regex matches

- `^0+` - 1 or more leading digits (those at the beginning of the string)
- `|` - or
- `\D+` - one or more non-digit symbols

```js
var re = /^0*|\D+/g; 
var str = '00567600ffg5566';
var result = str.replace(re, '');
document.body.innerHTML = str + " >>> " +  result;
```

Comment: Thank you !
Thank you also for the explanation!

Comment: @Thomas: [It works](https://regex101.com/r/fS1yC8/4). It removes the leading zeros and all non-digits inside the string. Moti, the `/g` in `/^0*/g` makes no sense since the start of string can only be matched once. Also, this regex may match an empty string, thus, it is best to replace the `*` with the `+` quantifier.