# how to retrieve substring from POST data response? JS

Tags: javascript, string, post, substring

I have a POST request that comes back as different percentages wrapped in a `<p>` tag based on the form sent. example:

```
htmlcode = "<p>20%</p >"
```

how would I get the substring, the percentage, as it changes every time a POST request is sent?

Comment: if `<p>` and `</p>` are always wrapping the percentage, you can replace them to nothing. It will leave you with only - say - '20%'. At that point, you just replace the "%" sign with nothing, and you get the number.

Comment: even without regex is pretty straigthforward. `let x = htmlcode.replace('<p>', '').replace('</p>', '').replace('%'. '');`

Comment: but since you do not need the html markup, I'd say this question is a duplicate of this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6649327/regex-to-remove-letters-symbols-except-numbers  `var number = htmlcode.replace(/\D+/g, '');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, why is your data wrapped in a `<p>...</p>` tag if you don't need it?

But to answer your question:

```js
const htmlcode = "<p>20%</p>";

// Simply substringing
console.log('substring', htmlcode.substring(3, htmlcode.length - 4));

// Using RegExp
const match = htmlcode.match(/^<p>(.*)<\/p>$/);
console.log('match', match[1]);
```

The RegExp allows you to later on filter out some other things, while the `substring` version is very static.

---

I noticed that the example in your question changed from `<p>20%</p>` to `<p>20%</p >`. Now my first approach won't work, but the 2nd one will when modifying the RegExp to account for optional whitespace:

```js
const htmlcode = "<p>20%</p >";

// Using RegExp
const match = htmlcode.match(/^<p>(.*)<\/p\s*>$/);
console.log('match', match[1]);
```

Comment: thanks for the fast reply, the code ran is outputting this in the console `Cannot read property 1 of null`

Comment: If you run the code snippet, you can see that it works. If `match` is null (therefore causing that error), it means that the RegExp didn't match. Therefore, your `htmlcode` doesn't look like `<p>...</p>`, so check what your HTML request returns.

Comment: first solution assumes percentage is expressed as 2 digits. what if `5%` or `100%`?

Comment: @GrafiCode the first solution skips the first 3 characters and the last 4 characters. It doesn't care how much characters there are between the tags.

Comment: Although I just saw the example in the question be edited to now include whitespace. I'll edit my answer to reflect this.

Comment: @KelvinSchoofs you were right I missed a space in the </p>. I edited question so you can look at it.

Comment: @BobbyByen I've modified my answer. The "3rd" approach now supports `</p>` and `</p >` (even with multiple spaces).

Comment: `var number = htmlcode.replace(/\D+/g, '');` this will keep only digits (i.e. it will remove the "%" sign too)

Comment: I just went with removing the tags, in case there could be different value formats in the future. Or more relevant, if there are percentages with decimals.

Comment: @KelvinSchoofs thanks for all the help! quick question, what would you do if there's a plenty amount of whitespace before the tag... just like how you solved the problem with `\s*` after the tag

Comment: You can always add another `\s*` in another spot to account for whitespace. If it's right before the end tag though, you'll need to change the `(.*)` into `(.*?)` to prevent it from eagerly including the whitespace too.

Comment: how would I get chance 30 from this string? `<span style="font-size:25px;border-radius: 10px;">chance 30</span>`.

Comment: Why is your API even wrapping your data in tags if you just want to get rid of them anyway? Seems like a bad idea

Comment: im sending a request to a site and want to just get the text so i can pass it on to a variable

Comment: @BobbyByen `cleanText = strInputCode.replace(/<\/?[^>]+(>|$)/g, "");` this basically strips all html tags from a string