# Remove special characters like space,bracket,plus symbol,hyphen from phone number string

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace, rhino

I am considering below cases to remove garbage values ,or space bracket from a telephone number string.

Below are the examples I am considering.

```
//Ignore Special char
phone = "+1-555-555-1234"
result = "15555551234"

phone = "1(800)555-0199"
result = "18005550199"

//Ignore Space
phone="555 555 1234"
result = "5555551234"


//If phone number contains spaces,parenthesis or some garbage character only consider digits.
phone = "9898871234567)"
result = "9898871234567"

//If + and parenthesis symbol is present
phone = "+11 111 111"
result = "11111111"

phone= "(22) 222-222"
result = "22222222"

//If hyphen is present
phone = "(22) 222-222"
result = "22222222"
```

How can I easliy achive this in javascript using regex?

Comment: What regexes have you tried?

Comment: "Ignore Special char" - why is it removed from the expected result if it should be ignored?

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: function removeSpecialCharactersFromNumber(number) {
  return number.replace(/[()\s+\-]/g, '');
} 

will do the trick

Comment: `number.replace(/[+-/(/)\s]/g, '');`

Comment: Alternative duplicate: [regex-to-remove-letters-symbols-except-numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6649327/regex-to-remove-letters-symbols-except-numbers)

Answer (score 1):

```js
const result = '11-11+11(33)'.replace(/\D/g, '');
// Remove any character that is NOT a number.
console.log(result)
```

Comment: Down voted because of obvious duplicates.

Comment: @MarkBaijens with respect, the example provided above as duplicate is generic, and not specific to this usecase.

Comment: No offence, but a quick search will show you there are plenty of specific duplicated anwers (as expected with such a generic question). See my comment under the question as an example.

Comment: @MarkBaijens absolutely, but the op doesn't know regex, hence the question. Sometimes a working example is enough to set them on the road to further discovery. Regex is not an easy language to understand among the best of developers

Comment: The OP tagged this question with `regex` and asks for an regex example which the duplicates perfectly provide. Answering questions like these add nothing to the community and Q&A database and should always be closed instead (with a friendly comment guiding the OP to the answer).

Comment: @MarkBaijens to be frank. The generic example is poor. Regex is complicated. A simple tutorial can help and maybe that'd be better than other our responses

Comment: The regex in the accepted answer of the duplicate that I posted in the question's comments is basically the same as yours: `/\D+/g` vs your `/\D/g`.  You did not post a tutorial or even elaborated your answer either. The OP doesn't need Stack Overflow to find a tutorial either. I really see no added value to answering this question over closing it. Multiple of the same questions on Stack Overflow is not desirable. See [question-close-reasons-definitions-and-guidance](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/417476/question-close-reasons-definitions-and-guidance) for more information.

Comment: @MarkBaijens The example you provided is string.replace(/^F0+/i) completely different. Also this is my tutorial - short and sweet: // Remove any character that is NOT a number

Comment: Last thing I say about this to prevent endless discussion. I never provided `string.replace(/^F0+/i)`. The duplicate used to close the question might not be the best. Therefore my comment in the question with a link to an alterntive duplicate. My point is that your answer is a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6649350/443523). Closing this question is the way to go instead of answering for the reasons mentioned above. That's the reason the community closed this question and that's why my downvote stands.